# Tabs with links images and description on SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience

I want to create tabs with links, images and description in **SharePoint online**?

Is there any web part is available for it? something like below image.

[image]

**P.S** I am using a new modern site.

Comment: Tab in the sense different links are available like **In tab1 some images, links and next tab some other images,  links.** for ex: When we open a browser with different tabs which contains different links.